# Method to serialize a class which contain BitmapImage : using 2 inherited class?

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When my application closes, I want to serialize some data to make it persistent for the next use of the application. I choose to serialize these data with Newtonsoft.JsonConverter.
But, I have a BitmapImage in my class, and it can't be serialized.

I'm bit stuck on this because I don't find a solution to keep my BitmapImage into my class (I need to keep it here) and being able to serialize this class.
I tried to create a inherited class which contains the BitmapImage, but I'm not allowed to create an implicit operator from my base class.

I want to have an object in my class which can be used to be a source for a Image binding, and be able to serialize this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just "Saving the BitMap to a file" and serializing the image file name only.

But, if you must serialize the bitmap, just save the bitmap to a MemoryStream as byte[].

```
byte[] byteArray;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
        Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
}
```

**Update:** 


Serialize your image via Image Path.

```
private string m_imagePath;

    public Image Image { get; private set; }

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return m_imagePath; }
        set 
        {
            m_imagePath = value;
            Image = Image.FromFile(m_imagePath);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyClass
{
    private string m_imagePath;

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // not serialized because mode is opt-in
    public Image Image { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return m_imagePath; }
        set
        {
            m_imagePath = value;
            Image = Image.FromFile(m_imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have a json object here, that has the Opt-In attribute, meaning you need to specify which properties are serialized.
This demo object has a Name property that is serialized, an ImagePath property that is serialized.
However, the Image property is not serialized. 
When you deserialize the object the image will load because the ImagePath setter has the needed funcionality.

I hope this helped, I tested it, and it works.
Rate if you like. Good Luck!

Comment: Actually, I using the BitmapImage via a Binding in a ListView. Im not sure it will work if I save the image file path.

Comment: Ok, So serialize the bitmap as a byteArray as shown. If your class implements ISerializable, in your GetObjectData make sure that you place the byteArray inside info.AddValue("BitMapByteArray", arr)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained it very well. 
In fact, I save some images in the ApplicationData.LocalFolder. I don't want to serialize them because they are already in memory.
Is it possible to bind an <Image> with the local file path ? (should I write with file://C:/blabla or only C:/blabla ?) 
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: With your updated solution, I won't be able to serialize my class because there is an Image object that can't be serialized ...

Comment: Excuse me, but you do not have to serialize each and every object inside a class. you choose what you want to serialize via info.AddValue

Comment: Hum, I'm using Newtonsoft.JsonConverter to serialize my datas. It doesn't contain AddValue method. What should I use to serialize ?

Comment: **oh yeah, very nice, I love it, and it work ! thanks you very much**

Comment: Image.FromFile? Where does it come from?