# How can i store my List<List<Class>> to a text file using C# in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, text

i'm trying to store a `List<List<Class>>` to a text file using C#, my class is like

```
public class cEspecie
{
    private string nombre;
    private BitmapImage imagen;
    private int tiempodevida;
    private int movilidad;
    private int decaimiento;
    private int tipo;
    private string colordelagrafica;
    private bool seleccion;


    public int Tipo
    {
        get
        {
            return tipo;
        }
        set
        {
            tipo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Nombre
    {
        get
        {
            return nombre;
        }
        set
        {
            nombre = value;
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage Imagen
    {
        get
        {
            return imagen;

        }
        set
        {
            imagen = value;
        }
    }

    public int TiempoDeVida
    {
        get
        {
            return tiempodevida;
        }
        set
        {
            tiempodevida = value;
        }
    }

    public int Movilidad
    {
        get
        {
            return movilidad;
        }
        set
        {
            movilidad = value;
        }
    }

    public int Decaimiento
    {
        get
        {
            return decaimiento;
        }
        set
        {
            decaimiento = value;
        }
    }

    public string ColorDeLaGrafica
    {
        get
        {
            return colordelagrafica;
        }
        set
        {
            colordelagrafica = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Seleccion
    {
        get
        {
            return seleccion;
        }
        set
        {
            seleccion = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
 List<List<cEspecie>> items1 = new List<List<cEspecie>>();
```

How can I take all my data from "items1" in order to store it inside a Text file using C#? and also how can I make it back in order to store it in another list?

Comment: Out of curiosity why arn't you using auto properties like `public bool Seleccion {get; set;}`? Also you really should follow the [.NET naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that leading lowercase `c` in `cEspecie` should not be there (or at least be a capital `C`).

Comment: The biggest problem here is the `BitmapImage`.  You will probably need a custom hook to transform the image into a path/URI, or encode it using Base64 or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to actually save the data using Xaml.  It's a fitting solution since you're already using WPF.

Simple example:

```
List<List<cEspecie>> items1 = new List<List<cEspecie>>();
// ... add items...
XamlServices.Save(@"c:\path\to\file.xaml", items1);
```

And then to load:

```
var items2 = XamlServices.Load(@"c:\path\to\file.xaml");
```

Note that for this to work, you will need to change `Imagen` from a `BitmapImage` to its base class, `BitmapSource`.  This will only work if the image was loaded with a URI or file path, and it will be saved using that URI/path.  If you want to prevent the `Imagen` property from being saved in the Xaml, you can annotate the property with `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]`.

Here's the Xaml file my test code created:

```
<List x:TypeArguments="List(w:cEspecie)"
      Capacity="4"
      xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:w="clr-namespace:WpfXUnit;assembly=WpfXUnit"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <List x:TypeArguments="w:cEspecie"
        Capacity="4">
    <w:cEspecie ColorDeLaGrafica="zomg"
                Decaimiento="42"
                Imagen="file:///w:/dump/test.png"
                Movilidad="76"
                Nombre="'ello gov'na"
                Seleccion="True"
                TiempoDeVida="32"
                Tipo="1" />
  </List>
</List>
```

Comment: Yea, I agree. It really says something when all of the other people who posted answers give you a +1 when their own answers are still sitting at 0.

Comment: Xaml is a pretty darned useful persistence format.  Far more capable than most people give it credit for.  I've used it for all manner of evil things >:>.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain We are all here to learn, and I never even considered using XAML for this. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would look into using [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) or [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to serialize/deserialize your data. That way you can easily store the data in a file, send it over a Web Service etc.

It would be simple using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), the only problem would be to store the Bitmap.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items1);
```

Depending on how you decide to store the bitmap, Json.NET is not able to store it as JSON, unless you do some magic.

The easiest way would be to not serialize the Bitmap property and instead load the Image when you deserialize the string.

A simple solution is available in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783647/method-to-serialize-a-class-which-contain-bitmapimage-using-2-inherited-class) stackoverflow post.

**Edit:**

This is an example based on the that stackoverflow post above, using your code.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Especie
{
    private string m_imagePath;

    [JsonProperty]
    public Tipo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int TiempoDeVida { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int Movilidad { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int Decaimiento { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string ColorDeLaGrafica { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool Seleccion { get; set; }

    // not serialized because mode is opt-in
    public Bitmap Imagen { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return m_imagePath; }
        set
        {
            m_imagePath = value;
            Imagen = Bitmap.FromFile(m_imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not going to be that easy because of the `BitmapImage` object.

Comment: Ah, damn missed that @ScottChamberlain. I updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

If all you had was basic types all you would need to do is put a [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your class and you could use a [`XmlSeralizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write it out to a file.

```
[Serializable]
public class cEspecie
{
   //...Snip...
}
```

However for that to work all of the elements inside the class must also be marked `[Serializable]`, unfortunately `BitmapImage` is not.

To work around this we mark the unseralizeable object to be skipped, we then provide a new property that can be seralized that can represent the image

```
[Serializable]
public class cEspecie
{
   //...Snip...

    [XmlIgnore] //Skip this object
    public BitmapImage Imagen
    {
        get { return imagen;  }
        set { imagen = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] //This creates a secret hidden property that does not show up in intellisense
    [XmlElement("Imagen")] //It uses the name of the real property for it's name
    public BitmapImageSearalizer ImagenSerialized
    {
        get
        {
            return new BitmapImageSearalizer(imagen);
        }
        set
        {
            imagen = value.GetSearalizedImage();
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
internal BitmapImageSearalizer
{
    public BitmapImageSearalizer(BitmapImage sourceImage)
    {
        //...Snip...
    }

    public BitmapImage GetSearalizedImage()
    {
        //...Snip...
    }

    //...Snip...
}
```

I leave it to you to write `BitmapImageSearalizer` I have not worked with the class enough to write it.

To show you a more complete known working example of how to do it, here is a snippet from one of my projects where I did this exact trick with just a plain [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 1 bit per pixel bitmap to use as the image source.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Bitmap BitmapImage
    {
        get { return _Bitmap; }
        set
        {
            if (value.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
                throw new FormatException("Bitmap Must be in PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed");
            _Bitmap = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("Bitmap")]
    public byte[] BitmapSerialized
    {
        get
        { // serialize
            if (BitmapImage == null) return null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BitmapImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        set
        { // deserialize
            if (value == null)
            {
                BitmapImage = null;
            }
            else
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(value))
                {
                    BitmapImage = new Bitmap(ms);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like that we covered XML, JSON and XAML. +1 ;)